# Stop Xcode 5 creating provisioning profiles?

Tags: xcode, ios7, xcode5, ios-provisioning, xcode5.0.1

Xcode 5 keeps creating a developer provisioning profile for one of my apps that I don't need. I have already tested the app with the Xcode Team Provisioning Profile and released it with another distribution profile and I do not require a development profile with a specific bundle id.

How do I stop Xcode from creating it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately, you don't!

I contacted Apple Developer Technical Support and sent them the following:

**DESCRIPTION OF PROBLEM - How do I import existing distribution Provisioning Profiles from the Provisioning Portal into Xcode 5 but without Xcode creating/managing new development "iOS Team Provisioning Profiles"? Another way to ask the question is, how do turn OFF Xcode Managed Provisioning Profiles, but still import existing profiles from portal?
STEPS TO REPRODUCE In the Provisioning Portal create a new bundle id and then create a new distribution provisioning profile. (but do NOT create a development profile). From within Xcode, go to Preferences > Accounts > Click Team Name > View Details > Click Refresh button. Xcode will now create a development profile that I do not want created, it will show up in both Xcode and the Provisioning Portal. I do NOT want Xcode to create any new profiles... I only want it to import all existing ones that are in the portal.**

This was the response I got back from Apple Developer Technical Support:

**Thank you for contacting Apple Developer Technical Support (DTS). Our engineers have reviewed your request and have concluded that there is no supported way to achieve the desired functionality given the currently shipping system configurations. If you would like for Apple to consider adding support for such features in the future, please submit an enhancement request via the Bug Reporter tool at: http://bugreport.apple.com**

So it appears that Apple has added a new feature (Xcode Managed Profiles) with no way to turn it off, and with the side effect of it creating unwanted provisioning profiles.

So please submit a bug report to http://bugreport.apple.com and specifically ask for the following... Ability to import provisioning profiles from provisioning portal along with the ability to turn off Xcode Managed Profiles.

Comment: Note that you CAN stop this from happening if you remove all devices from the Provisioning Portal. However the side effect is that you cannot import the provisioning profiles from within Xcode (Preferences > Accounts). You would need to manually download them from the Provisioning Portal and then manually import them into Xcode.

Comment: As of August 2015, this regrettably still appears to be the case. These automatic iOS Team Provisioning Profiles are driving me nuts. If you have a good grasp of setting up provisioning correctly, then these extra profiles just pollute an otherwise tidy & organised setup. Sort this out Apple & let us turn it off!